# How to bake texture of a Geometry Nodes object?

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-baking

I created a stone house through geometry nodes (each stone is not connected but is the same object), and gave each stone a different color through "Random Per Island".

I want to export this object to Unreal Engine 5 and want to keep stones with random colors. However, when I bake the texture, I can't unwrap UVs and bake the texture.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that you can bake textures from object to object. In your case make new mesh to bake to and make UV for it, Then bake stones from GN to simple mesh using *selected to active* option:

[image]